# How to Parse " Nested JSON " and set to POJO class

Tags: json, parsing, jackson, nested, pojo

Jackson , How to Parse " Nested JSON " and set to POJO class

Sales.json

```
{
    "data": {
       "modified_by": "mat",
       "name": "mak",
        "net_total": 0,
        "items": [
            {
                "owner": "shoaib shaikh",
                "modified_by": "mat",
                "doctype": "Item"
             }
        ],
        "owner": "shoaib shaikh",
        "apply_discount_on": "tesla" 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Describe your class Sales then do

`import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
...
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Sales staff = mapper.readValue(new File("D:\\staff.json"), Sales.class);`

Some link to help: https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Comment: `new File("D:\\staff.json")` can be string